# Date - Text converting YYYYDM to YYYYDDMM

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having truble converting date format with `YYYYDM` to `YYYYDDMM`
for example:

- `200111` to `20010101` or
- `2001233` to `20012303`

… and so on

the format was like `2001/1/1 I` removed the `/` and now I ended up with `200111` but still need it to be `20010101`. I cant think of anything.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

Dim k As Long
k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For p = 2 To k
    myString = sh.Cells(p, 1)
    newString = Replace(myString, "/", "")
    sh.Cells(p, 1).Value = newString
Next p
```

I'd very much appreciate it if u guys have any solution for this.

Comment: Looks like you should try testing the length of your input to determine where the month and day portion start and end. Is your data consistent? I.e. what does it look like for the 1st Dec 2001121 or 20011201 etc? How do you tell 21st Jan and 1st Dec apart?

Comment: well it was like 2001/12/1 and i turned it to 2001121 and now i'm starting to think I shouldn't have done that. I think i should test the string after "/" and see if it's between 1-9 and  if it is add  a 0 before that and if it's between 10 to 12 I should leave it alone and same thing for day part of the Date, but honesty I'm looking for a more simple way, like a smart formula or sth. I wonder if anyone could come up with sth... it'll be pretty useful in all languages...

Comment: Yeah you should leave the "/" in. Are you looking to convert to strings or to dates? Excel should have no problem understanding your date format with "/" in it.

Comment: Im trying to turn date to string except it's not Christian date it's "Shamsi" (we use this in Iran) so I need to work with strings....

Comment: Try converting the dates from the Shamsi calendar to the Gregorian calendar. Simply using the Shamsi dates in Excel isn't going to work because the days in months are inconsistent with each other.

Comment: The thing is that my date is already Shamsi , I just want to fix the format. I think the Datevaule and Format does it just a "mismatch" error in the end....

Comment: Trying to put Shamsi dates into the Excel functions isn't going to work. In the Gregorian calendar there aren't 31 days in the second month so it won't pass validation.

Comment: What about `2005112` - is it `2005-01-12` or `2005-11-02`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad form to add a second answer, but this is a purely string based implementation rather than relying on Excel's built in processing. This additional requirement is mentioned in the comments above .

The parameter aDate is a string in the format "2001/1/1". The result of the function is "20010101".

```
Public Function parseDate(aDate As String)

    Dim components() As String

    components = Split(aDate, "/")
    components(0) = Right("0000" & components(0), 4)
    components(1) = Right("00" & components(1), 2)
    components(2) = Right("00" & components(2), 2)
    parseDate = components(0) & components(1) & components(2)

End Function
```

Testing this in the VBA IDE:

```
' Sample date
? parseDate("2001/1/1")
20010101

' Date with multiple digits for month and day
? parseDate("2001/12/31")
20011231

' Invalid date, there is no checking for invalid dates
? parseDate("2001/88/99")
20018899
```

Comment: thanks bunch. this works perfectly too. and no error. u guys r the best.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Mortimer states, leave the / in the date and use the format function.

```
format(datevalue("2001/1/1"),"yyyymmdd")
```

datevalue is used to change string literal into a date.

```
? format(datevalue("2001/1/1"),"yyyymmdd")
20010101
```

Comment: I dont think it work on none Christian dates, Does it?

Comment: Once you have the year, month, and day, do you know the formula to get to Shamsi dates? Maybe you just need to code that piece to get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks u, It does work!!! only I get a "type mismatch" error in the end but the format and datevalue actually fixed it!! any thought on the error?!